# Is there any version of CLT that does not need independent $X_i$'s?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Is there any version of CLT does not need independent $X_i$'s? 
The reason I'm asking this is because I'm woking on a moving average problem. I have 3 pieces each by CLT converges in distribution to standard normal. However, when I combine the three pieces, they have some terms in common and are not independent?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of such theorem. See for instance [CLTs for mixing processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#CLT_under_weak_dependence) and Doukhan's book "[Mixing: Properties and Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387942149)".

See also chapter 7 in the book "[Weak Dependence: with examples and applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387699511)".